# Worklight adapter security

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Is there a way to secure a worklight adapter so that adapter procedures could only be invoked via the app itself? Currently, if I'm not mistaken, you can reach an adapter outside of an app which theoretically poses a security risk if session is hijacked.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is "no".  Invoking an adapter procedure is simply making an HTTP request to the server, so anything that could replicate what the app does, and has somehow intercepted an authenticated session, would be able to use the adapter procedure as if it were the app itself - the server has no way of knowing the difference.

If you are concerned about session hijacking, the best way to mitigate that risk is to have the session encrypted end-to-end - i.e., enable SSL on the MFP server, and contact the server using HTTPS rather than unencrypted HTTP.  That way, a third-party observing the traffic would not be able to hijack the session, since it will not have access to the private keys used to encrypt the session.

Comment: In reference to what @Kirill said " Currently, if I'm not mistaken, you can reach an adapter outside of an app". This is only possible if my procedure is not protected by a security test. If it is protected by the security test, could I still invoke it from outside the app? I think MofileFirst doesn't allow that.

Comment: You are correct - you can't invoke an adapter outside of an app if it is protected by a MobileFirst Platform security test.  But, one of the concerns in the question was what would happen if someone hijacked an existing session (with the security tests already done).  That concern could be mitigated by end-to-end encryption.

Comment: Even if the session is hijacked, how can someone invoke the adapter procedure from out side the app?

Comment: If someone had the ability to hijack an authenticated session, they could do any operation that session could do with it's existing authentication, including invoking protected adapter procedures.